# Extracting PostBack value in Jmeter

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter

I want to extract the PostBack password value in Jmeter but all my efforts so far are returning null.

The value needs to be extracted after clicking a button that sends this request:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ContentPlaceHolder4$lbAddRecord','')
```

A dialog appears with the password.

Using google developer tools, I can see the full response with the info I need:

```
<span id="txtPassword" TextMode="Password">Rq0&t*Y32H</span>
```

When I run the script in Jmeter, the response only contains:

```
1|#||4|9|pageRedirect||%2fWeb%2f|
```

I tried the following to extract the password value:

1. regular expression extractor:

`reference name: password
regular expression = <span id="txtPassword" TextMode="Password">(.+?)</span>
template: $1$
match no: 1
default value: null`

2. xpath extractor:

`reference name:password
xpath query: .//*[@id='txtPassword']
default value: null`

How do I have to change my extractor query to get the password value?

Comment: can you clarify your issue ? is it that the response does not contain the span with password or is it that your extractors are failing ? in the latter case can you show how you configured extractor and where you've put it ? thx

Comment: The extractor is failing and returning null. The extractor is placed under the sampler that is supposed to return the password value. I've tried both regex and xpath extractor with the configuration noted in the post.

Comment: can you show response you get in jmeter that you want to extract data from ?

Comment: The only response I get from Jmeter is 1|#||4|9|pageRedirect||%2fWeb%2f. When I check using devtools, I get a more detailed html response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem comes from the request that precedes the one you're trying to extract data from.

So investigate what is missing in it (headers, cookies, request parameter) that explain why you don't get the correct content.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the other requests and saw that I'm missing the cookies.

Comment: Also, since I'm testing an asp.net site, I needed to extract and use the _VIEWSTATE and _EVENTVALIDATION for the requests.